# What is the probability that 80 out of 450 people would respond yes to a question by chance, if the true probability of such a response is 0.3?

Tags: r, sample

I approached this question in R as follows:

prop.test(80, 450, 0.3, correct = FALSE), however, am getting an incorrect answer. Does anyone know what I am inputting in R incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a hypothesis test but the question reads as if it is asking you to compute the binomial's probability mass function.  You can do that with `dbinom(x =80 , size = 450, prob = 0.3)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look at this more mathematically, you can use the binomial distribution:

That would be (.3^80)(.7^(450-80))(450choose80)

This is the probability that 80 people respond yes, times the probability that 370 people respond no, multiplied by the number of ways that 80 of 450 people could respond yes.